# How do I remove wobble from my DIY table?

Tags: wood, table

I made this table:
[image: table]

This is how the legs are attached to the table:
[image: How legs attach to table]

It has 3 legs on the back and two on the front. The top is solid wood. It wobbles both from front to back and side to side (front to back is worse). What can I do to minimize the wobble knowing that I have limited tools and experience in wood working? 
I want to make the table sturdy by itself, so I don't want to screw it to the wall.
A solution with readily available materials and beginner friendly would be ideal. I enjoy solving problems like these, but I think in this case I lack the knowledge to figure out a good solution. Extra points for creative thinking.

Comment: When you say wobble, do you mean it sways or rocks? Rocks being that the feet aren't all touching the floor at the same time while swaying being that you can push the table top and it moves more than it should while all feet are touching the floor. If swaying, you'll need cross support like Harper suggested.

Comment: I mean it sways. Has I said in response to his comment, the problem is I don't know how to do it and I can't find any information on how to do it with the legs I have.

Comment: Can you weld? If so that is the strongest self standing way to sure up your table legs.

Comment: @David Unfortunately, I can't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table and legs and floor are turning into parallelograms.  This is because the legs have no resistance against swinging on their mounts.

I suspect that *these* legs are not designed to prevent this, because they expect the desk surface will be anchored in both dimensions by something else, e.g. Being attached to a wall.

You will either need to select different legs, or find a way to brace these.  This is why most desks and chairs have some sort of cross bracing between legs, but you need more than that, or you'll just have more parallelograms.

If it were me, I would use steel angled shelf brackets that have a nice triangle shape to them, and drill and tap appropriate machine screws into the legs, using the steel in the legs to hold the screws.  I would not drill through the hollow legs and use a bolt and nut, because all that would do is squash the hollow leg.  You would need to learn the fine art of using a hand tap, and it would also help to get centerpunches to get the pilot holes in the right place, but that is not excessively hard.  Just tedious.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking from other posts I've read, but I have no idea how to brace the legs or what I can use to do it. Maybe something like this would help, between the legs and table top:
https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/f585248a0b351faabb0e6533fdf331d5/6x6-knee-brace?hl=zh-cn
But how can I make this with the legs I have?

Comment: @Meruje - If you have a friend that knows welding they might be able to help.  Something as simple as connecting the legs to each other part way down could help.

Comment: @IronEagle Also another thought that passed through my mind, but unfortunately I don't know anyone who knows how to weld. Is there anything I can find at a hardware store that can fulfill the same purpose, without having to weld?

Comment: A quick and cheap fix is getting some angle metal, aluminum or slotted steel, from a hardware store and screwing it between each set of legs at a angle, not straight. 45 degrees works well. Only need one piece between each set of legs. Be sure to get self-tapping screws as well so they will screw into the legs fairly easily.

Comment: @ Merjue - angle iron, like mentioned above, could work well.  Joints could be screwed or bolted, instead of being welded.  Or perhaps threaded rod between the legs, with a pipe as a spacer?  Given how the table legs are attached to the top, some more square tubing attached by bolting a flush T fitting for square tubing (something like this: https://www.teksupply.com/contractor/supplies/prod1;ts_conduit_fittings;pg104624.html )

Comment: @IronEagle I assure you, the table legs are hollow and any attempt to bolt *through* them wiill crush them.  If not the bolting, the stress they will be placed under.

Comment: @Harper, you are right. The legs are hollow. Can you explain what you mean by "using the steel in the legs"? Also, what would I be attaching to each side of the steel angled shelf brackets?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch How would the self tapping screws attach the angle iron to the legs? And would I need to cut that 45 degree angle on the angle metal?

Comment: Using the link below as an example, it should overlap enough for you to get a screw in. Worst case scenario, you may need to drill a hold for the screw in the angle iron which isn't a big deal if you have a drill and a bit just bigger than the screw diameter. You will need a hole if you use solid angle iron. Make sure you use aluminum or steel like the link and not iron. Iron is harder.    https://m.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-6-ft-x-1-5-in-Plated-Steel-Slotted-Angle/3059263

Comment: @HazardousGlitch And the bolt doesn't need a nut to stay attached to the leg? Sorry but I really have no experience working with metal.

Comment: Self-tapping screws will be easier than bolts because with bolts, you'll need to drill holes in each leg. Self-tapping screws look like normal screws for the most part but the ends of them are designed to bore their own hole as they are screwed in. If using aluminum, be sure to drill a hole first instead of trying to screw through that and the leg because you won't be able to pull it as tight to the leg or at least not without a few tries.

Comment: I think I'm gonna try Harper's angled shelf brackets, since it seems like a cleaner and simpler solution, with @HazardousGlitch self-tapping screws. If it works out I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: The problem with self-tapping screws is their coarse thread pitch won't give good purchase into the metal.  Which means they will be weak.  That's why they're not allowed for ground screws.  Also, it's hit and miss whether they work at all, because they encourage careless selection of drill size.  Tappign calls for a precise choice.   Now you can get the best of both worlds with self-tapping machine screws aka bolts, which have a fine thread.

Comment: I can't really distinguish between  self-tapping screws and  self-tapping machine screws. Are any of these self-tapping machine screws?
http://www.leroymerlin.pt/Site/Produtos/Ferragens/Ferragens-de-fixacao/Parafusos.aspx#next=0&size=24&order=0&type=gallery&min=0&max=71&totalMin=0&totalMax=71&filter=8783%3A1640401037%3A-1833246393%3A996041138

Answer (score 2):

Since the table is wide and not very thick, even were you to correct the issue now, it likely would warp a bit over time  -- specifically, the middle of the side with two legs will sink slightly. Therefore, any remedy should be *adjustable* to compensate for that sag.

You could buy and install [adjustable furniture levelers](https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=a9_asi_1?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Afurniture%20levelers&keywords=furniture%20levelers&ie=UTF8&qid=1545268095), or you could devise your own, depending on the design of the legs... or, for the three back legs, which are out of the way, insert thin siding shingles or similar inclined planes, which can be pushed in as needed (nothing would be needed for the front legs, if you don't mind a *slight* slant towards the front).

Comment: I've tried putting some cardboard beneath some of the legs, but I don't think it's a leveling problem, but rather a structural problem since there is no bracing between legs. I've also added two steel strips to the under side of the table to avoid the middle from sinking. You can see one of them in the second image. Still, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The steel angle-iron is a good idea. If you put some diagonally, it would also help, because the V it makes with the other brace across the top forms a strong triangle.